# iPhone app - fork or create a new version?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I have an iphone app that has been downloaded in the last two months by 150,000 persons. This app has in-app purchases and thousands of people bought them.

I have decided to create an iPad version of that app. On the way doing that, I decided to rewrite the app, making it easier. But in order to do so, I had to create a new interface. Now that I have this new app for iPad, I have created an iPhone version out of it.

My question is: should I release this iPhone version as a upgrade to the current version or create a new app?

My answer is not money related at this point. I ask this because I had an app in the past that I changed radically like that, and I got several people complaining they preferred the old interface. All I have to say is: there's no comparison in quality of the new interface with the old one. The new one is far superior, is easier and more intuitive and requires far less clicks to get the results. The new interface is totally in OpenGL (10 times faster) than the old one in Quartz. I would say the new interface is 80% similar to the old one, regarding to the workflow needed to get the final results.

Having in mind the old timers that will probably complain about the new interface and people that will get lost after seeing a new interface, what should I do? Create a new application or a version of the current one? Have in mind that if I create a new one, people who bought in-app purchases on the old version will have to buy them again.

What do you guys would do? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are upgrading a product and as you mentioned yourself, people already invested in it so launching a new version as a new product would require them to repurchase all of it, which is worse then making them adjust to the new approach. People will always complain, that's in our nature, so don't be bothered by that. Even if you have the best product people will try to bring you down. Trust your gut and if you personally use your product and find your new version much better then you will be fine upgrading it. If you need to test the user experiance on the new interface take a look at [heatma.ps SDK](https://heatma.ps)

Answer (score 1):

I'd release it as an upgrade. As Cyprian said, you have in-app purchase and you don't want to hurt the people who already bought it.

Comment: THANKS! I will do a upgrade then.

Answer (score 0):

As you say most people will like the new UI more, and I'll assert ALL people will like not paying for in app purchases again.   So the course of most happiness and fewest complaints is make the new universal one an upgrade.  No fork.